# Using Dynamic JSON in Silverlight 5 - not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, json.net

Does the use of c# dynamic types to add JSON array to a JObject work in Silverlight?

I have installed the latest JSON.NET 6.0.2 into VS2012. I want to create a JSON object in my c# code using the 'dynamic' method as shown in the documentation. However it doesn't work at runtime. I get an error adding a JArray where it states "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Sections'".

Example code:

```
dynamic state = new JObject();
state.Add("Date", DateTime.Now);  // works
state.Sections = new JArray() as dynamic;  // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

i am doing the same thing and Its working fine in Latest Version ..Now 
You Can Serialize and Di-serialize Using Dynamic

```
        dynamic state = new JObject();
        state.Add("Date", DateTime.Now);  
        state.Sections = new JArray() as dynamic;  
        var _strDJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state);
        var _strDDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(_strDJSON);
```